# vmware + active directory 2003 + windows xp sp2 + Fujitsu Zero Client + GPO propagation issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-xp, group-policy

i am trying to set up a domain controller with windows server 2008 (2003 functional level), and windows xp sp2 clients (both virtualized on a Fujitsu vmware server).

My windows xp sp2 clients have been patched to support with the following patches:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7707
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3628

When i create GPOs, and link them to a OU, they do not propagate to clients. If i link them to groups, some work and other doesn't. If i link them to the Domain, all of them work on windows xp clients. It can be seen on server when, after applying "gpupdate /force", you read the logs from "gpresult /r".

whats going on? i would appreciate if somebody could give me a clue about my issues.

thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Does `actually configured as 2003 compatible` mean that you're at a 2003 Domain and Forest functional level in Active Directory? Also, what do you mean when you say that `"My main issue here is the following case. My windows xp sp2 images have been patched to support AD 2008"`? There's no patching necessary unless you're talking about installing the Group Policy Client Side Extensions. You also don't like GPOs to groups, you link them to Domains, Sites, or OUs. What are you actually doing? Please take a moment to consider rewriting this with clearer terminology.

Comment: i modified my question. Sorry if i didn't write it accurately.regards

Comment: @MDMarra, i modified my question. Sorry if i didn't write it accurately.regards

Comment: What do you mean by `"link them to groups"` though? You don't link GPO to groups. You can link them to OUs and filter by groups, but you don't link them directly to groups. And why doesn't your XP machine have SP3?

Comment: @MDMarra, ok, lets forget about groups.When i link the GPO to an OU, it doesn't work. When i link to the entire domain, it works. I tried it with SP3 also.

Comment: You do realize that computer policies only apply to computer objects and user policies only apply to user objects, right? Under normal circumstances if you have a computer policy defined and link it to an OU of users, nothing will happen.